# Native method not found: org.opencv.core.Mat.n_Mat:()J

Tags: android, opencv, android-studio

I'm using native android Opencv 3.1.0 library
but always show error like this

> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native method not found: org.opencv.core.Mat.n_Mat:()J

This my Code

```
package com.example.saya.cameraopencv;

public class Hasil extends AppCompatActivity{

private TextView coba;
private ImageView gambarskrg;
private Mat rgba;

final String TAG = "Hello World";

private BaseLoaderCallback mOpenCVCallBack = new BaseLoaderCallback(this) {
    @Override
    public void onManagerConnected(int status) {
        switch (status) {
            case LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS:
            {
                Log.i(TAG, "OpenCV loaded successfully");           
            } break;
            default:
            {
                super.onManagerConnected(status);
            } break;
        }
    }
};
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.hasil_activity);
    OpenCVLoader.initAsync(OpenCVLoader.OPENCV_VERSION_3_1_0, this, mOpenCVCallBack);
    Bundle i = getIntent().getExtras();

    gambarskrg = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.gambar);

    String gambar = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ "/Coba/Coba_1476987074709.jpg";

    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(gambar);

    Log.i(TAG, "Trying to load OpenCV library");
    if (!OpenCVLoader.initAsync(OpenCVLoader.OPENCV_VERSION_3_1_0, this, mOpenCVCallBack))
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "Cannot connect to OpenCV Manager");
    }
    else {
        Log.e(TAG, "Berhasil");
        try {
            detectEdges(bmp);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

private void detectEdges(Bitmap bmp){
    Mat rgba = new Mat();
    Utils.bitmapToMat(bmp, rgba);

    Mat edges = new Mat(rgba.size(), CvType.CV_8UC4);
    Imgproc.cvtColor(rgba, edges, Imgproc.COLOR_RGBA2GRAY, 4);
    Imgproc.Canny(edges, edges, 80, 100);

    Bitmap resultBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(edges.cols(), edges.rows(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Utils.matToBitmap(edges, resultBitmap);
    int nh = (int) ( resultBitmap.getHeight() * (512.0 / resultBitmap.getWidth()) );
    Bitmap scaled = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(resultBitmap, 512, nh, true);
    gambarskrg.setImageBitmap(scaled);
}
```

}

and this the logcat

> 10-21 04:02:32.333 21528-21528/com.example.saya.cameraopencv E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                  Process: com.example.saya.cameraopencv, PID: 21528
>                                                                                  java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native method not found: org.opencv.core.Mat.n_Mat:()J
>                                                                                      at org.opencv.core.Mat.n_Mat(Native Method)
>                                                                                      at org.opencv.core.Mat.(Mat.java:24)
>                                                                                      at com.example.saya.cameraopencv.Hasil.detectEdges(Hasil.java:88)
>                                                                                      at com.example.saya.cameraopencv.Hasil.onCreate(Hasil.java:79)
>                                                                                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java)
>                                                                                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java)
>                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java)
>                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java)
>                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java)
>                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java)
>                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java)
>                                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java)
>                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java)
>                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java)
>                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java)
>                                                                                      at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:132)
>                                                                                      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few issues with the code. In your `onCreate` method, you call the `OpenCVLoader.initAsync` method twice, first time after `setContentView`, second time in the if statement after the `Log.i(TAG, "Trying to load OpenCV library")` message. You should only call the `OpenCVLoader.initAsync` method once, many of the examples that come with the OpenCV4Android SDK do this from the `onResume` method. To get a better idea of why this is, check out [this article](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html#Lifecycle) which describes the Activity lifecycle.

The second issue here is that you are attempting to create a `Mat` object before OpenCV has finished initialising. You must first wait for the async task that calls the OpenCV initialisation method to return back to the UIThread before you create a `Mat` object. When the OpenCV initialisation thread has finished running, it calls the `onManagerConnected` method. So to fix your issue, you must call your Mat initialisation code in the `onManagerConnected` method to ensure it is only called after the OpenCV initialisation code finishes executing. Here is an example of how it should look:

```
private Bitmap bmp;
final String TAG = "Hello World";    

private BaseLoaderCallback mLoaderCallback = new BaseLoaderCallback(this) {
    @Override
    public void onManagerConnected(int status) {
        switch (status) {
            case LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS: {
                Log.i(TAG, "OpenCV loaded successfully");
                try {
                    detectEdges(bmp);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            break;
            default: {
                super.onManagerConnected(status);
            }
            break;
        }
    }
};

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (!OpenCVLoader.initDebug()) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Internal OpenCV library not found. Using OpenCV Manager for initialization");
        OpenCVLoader.initAsync(OpenCVLoader.OPENCV_VERSION_3_1_0, this, mLoaderCallback);
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, "OpenCV library found inside package. Using it!");
        mLoaderCallback.onManagerConnected(LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.hasil_activity);
    Bundle i = getIntent().getExtras();
    String gambar = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ "/Coba/Coba_1476987074709.jpg";
    bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(gambar);
}

private void detectEdges(Bitmap bmp){
    Mat rgba = new Mat();
    Utils.bitmapToMat(bmp, rgba);

    Mat edges = new Mat(rgba.size(), CvType.CV_8UC4);
    Imgproc.cvtColor(rgba, edges, Imgproc.COLOR_RGBA2GRAY, 4);
    Imgproc.Canny(edges, edges, 80, 100);

    Bitmap resultBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(edges.cols(), edges.rows(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Utils.matToBitmap(edges, resultBitmap);
    int nh = (int) ( resultBitmap.getHeight() * (512.0 / resultBitmap.getWidth()) );
    Bitmap scaled = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(resultBitmap, 512, nh, true);
    ((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.gambar)).setImageBitmap(scaled);
}
```

Also, because you read the image from external memory, you may need to ask for user permission to read from memory depending on the Android version you are targeting. You do this by adding the following code to your android manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, you save my time